# rails trying to use datepicker and set the firstday to Monday

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, date, datepicker

I can't seem to set my datepicker to start the week on Monday.
I was able to change to dd/mm/yyyy by adding `$.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = "dd/mm/yyyy";` in vendor/assets/javascript/calander.js but this isn't changing the start day. I'm also using bootstrap.

I've tried:

```
$(document).ready->
$('#datepicker').datepicker
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
firstDay: 1
return
```

in my associated coffee file.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm still a noob too, and I've never tried using JS for dates.   However, I have the functionality you are looking for.   I use Platformatec's simple_form in my application.   I have a field that accepts a date in the model.   My form is very simple.

```
<%= f.input :start_date, as: :date, html5: true %>
<%= f.input :expiration_date, as: :date, html5: true %>
```

I get a nice calendar with this.   Now, I understand it may not as cleanly produce with older IE but I'd look at this and avoid the JS altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [George](http://geotho.github.io/code/2016/02/22/reject-unrecognised-parameters.html) for helping me with what to do.
I was trying to use jquery datepicker rather than [bootstrap datepicker.](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html)
I got what I needed with this...

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#refresh_startdate').datepicker
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    weekStart: 1
  return
```